# NestJS Mapped Typed - Nested objects

Tags: swagger, nestjs, mapped-types, class-transformer

In NestJS I want to use `PickType()` with a class, which has nested class properties.

**Example:**

```
export class Product {
    status: string;
    payment: {
      status: string;
      type: string;
   }
}
```

It should result in the swagger documentation as following DTO:

```
class PartialClass {
    payment: {
       status: string,
       type: string
    }
}
```

But the following implementation does not work:

```
class PartialClass {
    @ApiProperty({
      type: () => PickType(Videochat, ['payment']),
     })
    payment: Pick<Videochat['payment'], 'type' | 'status'>;
}
```

It returns an empty payment class property:

```
class PartialClass {
    payment: {
    }
}
```

So i guess PickType can't handle nested Types.

I tried also:

```
type: () => PickType(PickType(Videochat, ['payment']), ['status', 'type'])
```

but it also not working.

Comment: I believe you need to set it like this `type: PickType(Videochat, ['payment'])`

Answer (score -1):

You can handle it this way, let's assume we have the following class:

```
type User = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  address: {
    street: string,
    zipcode: string,
    geo: {
      lat: string,
      lng: string,
    },
  },
};
```

to pick user with address you can simply do `type UserWithOnlyAddress = Pick<User, 'address'>;`

in case you have to pick user with address's street only you can handle it:

```
type Pick2<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]> = {
  [P1 in K1]: {
    [P2 in K2]: (T[K1])[P2];
  };
};


type UserWithOnlyStreetAddress = Pick2<User, 'address', 'street'>;
```

And for picking at three levels

```
type UserWithOnlyGeoLat = Pick3<User, 'address', 'geo', 'lat'>;

type User = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  address: {
    street: string,
    zipcode: string,
    geo: {
      lat: string,
      lng: string,
    },
  },
};

type Pick3<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1], K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2]> = {
  [P1 in K1]: {
    [P2 in K2]: {
      [P3 in K3]: ((T[K1])[K2])[P3];
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: `I want to use PickType()` is the exact opposite of `here you go use Pick<>`